# Possible to change password in DRF without the previous password?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Say I had a setup that was similar to an office with a system admin.  But instead of using email to reset passwords, the system admin did it himself, and then got the password to the user through some other fashion.  Is this possible to do in Django?  Can I use the hash of the previous password somehow?  Is there possibly a way to overwrite the rest-auth in the serializer and view?  Please let me know if you guys have any methods for this. I haven't really come across anything that isn't email or Django frontend stuff.

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. Do you mind elaborating exactly what your issue is and what you are trying to solve. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might be of help on how to ask a better question

Comment: Do you want to reset password from Admin site and send the password to the user?

Comment: If you are a superuser you can easily change password of any user from django's admin panel without knowing the old password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible indeed. The admin could use the admin interface.

Just implement a custom Django admin action for that.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/

And use `user.set_password` so you won't have to deal the hash for the previuos password.

If you don't want to use the admin interface you still can use user.set_password from any view.

Comment: Don't worry, I enjoy helping and solving problems more than rep points  ;)